# How to merge product description and additional information tabs?

Tags: magento, tabs, attributes, magento-1.7

I am using a Modern theme which separates all information into tabs. I want to merge some of the tabs as visitors hate clicking.

I spent hours searching, but can't fine one that actually works.

Here is example of what I want to achieve:

http://www.teasta.com/chocolate-mint-rooibos-herbal-tea-4oz-tin.html

You can see description appears just above the Additional information (attributes)

How do I do this in Magento 1.7.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Remove Additional Information Tab comment following code from catalog.xml

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
```

For display Additional Information in Product Description Tab paste following code in
"catalog/product/view/description.phtml" file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes', '', array('template'=> 'catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml'))->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: @Pankaj, rather than commenting out code from a core file, i.e. catalog.xml, it is best practice to use the your theme's layout local.xml file to update remove items. e.g. `<reference name="product.info.tabs">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>additional</name></action>
</reference>`.  Otherwise your changes will be lost when you upgrade Magento.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the tabs are added via the layout xml (see catalog.xml) in your package by the method "addTab".

Example:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>
```

You could comment that line in catalog.xml and edit `app/design/frontend/your_package/default/catalog/product/view.phtml` and echo the information you want ;)

Comment: i actually like to edit the view.phtml file , since my custom theme inherit description file from base ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My settings were inside /app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/local.xml changing what's inside the title tags

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >

            <!-- Product description -->
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>

            <!-- Product attributes -->
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Specifications</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
```