# How to display product description and additional information in single page without tab

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento community version 1.7.0.2

Currently my website has product description shown in tab as shown in the image below, but I want to show "product description" together with "additional information" and Reviews in product page without any tab but couldn't find any information how to do that

Anyway, the "additional information" is not shown in the product page, how to enable it in the Admin Panel ?

I am new to magento. Please help.

Current layout (tabs):

```
| Product Description | Reviews | Product Tags
+---------------------+---------+-------------
```

Want to change it to this layout (without tabs):

**Product Description**

description content ... ... ...

**Product Additional Information**

additional information content ... ... ...

Comment: checkout this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489287/magento-merge-product-description-and-addition-information-tab

Answer (score -1):

Just make the attributes you're using "Visible on Frontend" through the attributes' settings and they'll appear under the "Additional Information" tab, next to "Product Description".

Comment: Question says "Without using tabs". Pretty sure this is not a helpful answer.