# magento changing product description tab title

Tags: magento, tabs

I am trying Magento and one thing I'm trying to do, but just cannot achieve, is just change the title of the Product's Description tab.

I've tried searching online but can online find tutorials for adding tabs (which don't work)

All i am after is just to change the product description tab.

Comment: You have to look for it in magento theme / skin files.

Comment: I've tried but i don't know what files / what section of code to look for

Comment: For instance if your current design is "modern" then the path to look for files will be `MAGENTO_INSTALLATION_FOLDER\app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\catalog\product` then check files there.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help, but there is nothing about the title of the tabs, i checked the tabs.phtml and there is no 'description' that i can just change to 'Prod. Desc'

Comment: Read this. It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489287/magento-merge-product-description-and-addition-information-tab?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change it in file:

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/layout/catalog.xml
```

inside there is a code line:

```
<action method="setTitle">
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
</action>
```

you just need to change `<value>` node and put what you want